# popup at same time when download begin wordpress widget

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am creating site http://competension.com.

I have to develop widget in which there is a download link and can download docx file.

Its working fine but now my client want while his docx file download on users computer its display a popup box by some msg.

```
<img src="http://competension.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/click-here-to-download.gif">
<form method="get" action="http://competension.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/compt.docx"  onclick="myFunction()">
    <button>Dawnload</button>
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       alert("Hello\nHow are you?");
    }
</script>
```

but its displaying popup and when i click ok then downloading start. I want both happen at the same time.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: try `onsubmit="myFunction()"`

Comment: still the same result